# how to use custom model user in django-rest-framework-simple-jwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

simple-jwt currently issues token using superuser but, i wanna use my custom User Model. (i defined custom User model as below.)

```py
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__


class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("name", "password")
```

my question is that could i receive token using custom user model at simple-jwt?

if simple-jwt uses custom User model, please tell me how to use custom User model.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me try**
Assuming you installed **djangorestframework_simplejwt** correctly

*Just paste this at the end of your*
**settings.py**

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',
}
```

*here UserSerializer uses CustomUserModel i.e.*
**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = []
        read_only_fields = ( ,)
```

And add the serializer which overrides the default serializer validate method of the TokenObtainPairView

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer


class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
       # The default result (access/refresh tokens)
       data = super().validate(attrs)
       refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

       # assign token 
       data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
       data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

       # extra fields
       data['age'] = self.user.age
       return data
```

With the help of this I get the "age" model field of the CustomUser i made,**on calling the login end points.**

User this serializer in your views class and then call the url of this views
After callilng this url

Returned data as follow:

```
{
"refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9..............",
"access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...............",
"username": "Shubham",
"id": 4,
"age": 100,
"description": "Slow shubham gadwal mehra try to understand."
```

}

Answer (score 0):

SimpleJWT uses AUTH_USER_MODEL for the JWT generation, if you plan to have more than one Authentication User, you should adjust the logic for that specific case. I hope this answers helps.